# Adding a custom Toolbar to a FragmentActivity (that uses a ViewPager)?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I'm using a `ViewPager` to slide across 3 screens at the moment, which is initialised in a `FragmentActivity`.

My aim is to have a `Toolbar` or `ActionBar` that remains the same for each page in the `ViewPager` - apart from the title, which changes depending on the page you are on.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

I have tried the following

```
mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
getActionBar().setTitle(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

But I keep getting an error setActionBar (android.widget.Toolbar) in `Activity` cannot be applied to android.widget.support.v7.Toolbar.

Any ideas?

Comment: in onPageChanged method call the setTitle(String), you do not need to use toolbar.

Comment: Thanks. I still want a toolbar to add a menu and other things.

Comment: Then call setTitle() with getSupportActionbar after setting with toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

When using the support libraries, you need to use the support methods.

```
mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mActionToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

You should be golden if you replace your code to the code above.